# No se me encriptan mis contraseñas en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encriptación

lo que pasa es que necesito encriptar las contraseña que se introduzcan en el sitio web, pero resulta que cuando se introducen las contraseñas y se guardan en la base de datos, las contraseñas llegan sin encriptar, este es el codigo de la pagina signup.php

```
<?php 
    require 'database.php';
    $message = '';
    if (!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, email, password) VALUES (:usuario, :email, :password)";
        $stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':usuario',$_POST['usuario']);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':password',$_POST['password']);

        if ($stmt -> execute()) {
            $message = 'Se ha creado su cuenta satisfactoriamente en HardSoft';
        }
        else {
            $message = 'Lo sentimos, pero ha ocurrido un problema con la base de datos';
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registrarse</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php require 'partials/header.php' ?>
    <?php if (!empty($message)):
    ?>
        <p><?= $message ?></p>
    <?php
    endif; 
    ?>
    <h1>Registrarse</h1>
    <span>ó <a href="login.php">Iniciar Sesión</a></span>
    <form action="signup.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirme la contraseña">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cambia `$stmt -> bindParam(':password',$_POST['password']);` por `$stmt -> bindParam(':password',$password);`

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, pero no te puedo calificar el comentario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

﻿﻿cambia `$stmt -> bindParam(':password',$_POST['password']);` por `$stmt -> bindParam(':password',$password);`

Comment: vale, en 9 minutos te la marco como correcta, gracias